# How to get the numeric value in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm doing a project which i need to use OCR. Upload image and the text on the image will be retrieved. 
When i'm working on this OCR, the response i got it is in JSON format. I want to get all the numeric values with "text" as the key.

I only managed to get all the values in text which looks like this

[image]

I want the result to be like

```
1,381
1,210
1,240
1,160
1,090
1,020
```

This is the JSON

```
   {
      "boundingBox": "1087,1201,228,83",
      "words": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "1087,1201,228,83",
          "text": "Sonic"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "boundingBox": "882,1287,700,55",
      "words": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "882,1287,151,49",
          "text": "Bacon"
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "1048,1287,170,49",
          "text": "Double"
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "1232,1287,350,55",
          "text": "Cheeseburger"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "boundingBox": "1014,1391,418,109",
      "words": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "1014,1391,244,109",
          "text": "1,240"
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "1287,1393,145,97",
          "text": "cal"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "boundingBox": "853,1422,59,59",
      "words": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "853,1422,59,59",
          "text": "O"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "boundingBox": "970,1655,478,90",
      "words": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "970,1655,278,90",
          "text": "Burger"
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "1270,1655,178,90",
          "text": "King"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "boundingBox": "917,1753,630,55",
      "words": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "917,1754,142,54",
          "text": "Triple"
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "1071,1754,225,54",
          "text": "Whooper"
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "1308,1753,239,50",
          "text": "Sandwich"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "boundingBox": "853,1855,576,109",
      "words": [
        {
          "boundingBox": "853,1892,59,59",
          "text": "e"
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "1018,1855,236,109",
          "text": "1,160"
        },
        {
          "boundingBox": "1283,1857,146,97",
          "text": "cal"
        }
      ]
    }
```

This is the functions that i used javascript and html

```js
function traverseJSON (jsonStruct, initialValue) {
 
 for (x in jsonStruct) {
  if (typeof(jsonStruct[x]) == "object") {
   initialValue = traverseJSON(jsonStruct[x], initialValue);
  } else {
   if(x == "text"){
    initialValue += jsonStruct[x] + " "; 
   }
   
  }
  
 }
 return initialValue;
 
}
```

```html
        .done(function(data) {
            // Show formatted JSON on webpage.
   traverseThis(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        })
```

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify what *I want to get all the numeric values with "text" as the key.* means and show an example of what you expect your results to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if below code is what you need. I've just implemented this using pure Javascript functions [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) and [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```js
    let input=[{
     "boundingBox": "1087,1201,228,83",
     "words": [{
      "boundingBox": "1087,1201,228,83",
      "text": "Sonic"
     }]
    }, {
     "boundingBox": "882,1287,700,55",
     "words": [{
       "boundingBox": "882,1287,151,49",
       "text": "Bacon"
      },
      {
       "boundingBox": "1048,1287,170,49",
       "text": "Double"
      },
      {
       "boundingBox": "1232,1287,350,55",
       "text": "Cheeseburger"
      }
     ]
    }, {
     "boundingBox": "1014,1391,418,109",
     "words": [{
       "boundingBox": "1014,1391,244,109",
       "text": "1,240"
      },
      {
       "boundingBox": "1287,1393,145,97",
       "text": "cal"
      }
     ]
    }, {
     "boundingBox": "853,1422,59,59",
     "words": [{
      "boundingBox": "853,1422,59,59",
      "text": "O"
     }]
    }, {
     "boundingBox": "970,1655,478,90",
     "words": [{
       "boundingBox": "970,1655,278,90",
       "text": "Burger"
      },
      {
       "boundingBox": "1270,1655,178,90",
       "text": "King"
      }
     ]
    }, {
     "boundingBox": "917,1753,630,55",
     "words": [{
       "boundingBox": "917,1754,142,54",
       "text": "Triple"
      },
      {
       "boundingBox": "1071,1754,225,54",
       "text": "Whooper"
      },
      {
       "boundingBox": "1308,1753,239,50",
       "text": "Sandwich"
      }
     ]
    }, {
     "boundingBox": "853,1855,576,109",
     "words": [{
       "boundingBox": "853,1892,59,59",
       "text": "e"
      },
      {
       "boundingBox": "1018,1855,236,109",
       "text": "1,160"
      },
      {
       "boundingBox": "1283,1857,146,97",
       "text": "cal"
      }
     ]
    }]

    function traverseJSON (jsonStruct, initialValue) {
     
     for (x in jsonStruct) {
      if (typeof(jsonStruct[x]) == "object") {
       initialValue = traverseJSON(jsonStruct[x], initialValue);
      } else {
       if(x == "text"){
            if(!isNaN(jsonStruct[x].replace(',',''))){
        initialValue += jsonStruct[x] + "\n";
             }
       }
       
      }
      
     }
     return initialValue;
     
    }

console.log(traverseJSON(input,''))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly:

```
function getNumbers(data = []) {
  return data.reduce((arr, entry) => {
    const withNumbers = entry.words.filter(wordEntry => !!Number(wordEntry.text.replace(",", ".")))
    return arr.concat(withNumbers);
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jsonpath](http://jsonpath.com) - `$[*].words[*].text` to get all the text from your json.

Sample output from your input

```
"Sonic",
"Bacon",
"Double",
"Cheeseburger",
"1,240",
"cal",
"O",
"Burger",
"King",
"Triple",
"Whooper",
"Sandwich",
"e",
"1,160",
"cal"
```

Use regex - `\d+(,\d+)*` for parse this output. You can try it online here [here](https://regexr.com/).